# CORS policy error with Java + Spring in an ajax query

Tags: java, jquery, spring, gradle, cors

working with Java 11, eclipse, Gradle and spring in an ubuntu os

While my POST calls are working fine, the GET calls to the server are blocked due to the CORS policy with below error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/dices/players?{}'
>   from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

the javascript for the POST and GET calls is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#newUserButton').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/dices/players',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
            data: JSON.stringify({"name":$('#newUserInput').val()}),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#newUserJumbo').append('<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">El usuari ' + data.name + ' ha estat creat</div>');
                },
            error: function(e){
                console.log(e);
            }
        });
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#searchUserButton').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/dices/players',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
            data: JSON.stringify({"idPlayer":$('searchUserInput').val()}),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#modifyUserUl').append('<button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="' + data.id + ' onclick=modifyUser(' + data.id + '>id: ' + data.id + ', nom: ' + data.name + '</button>');
            },
            error: function(e){
                console.log(e);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

To handle the CORS at server side, i'm using the below class that i've found in a mozilla mdnwebDoc  [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) which is working fine with the POST call, but fails on the GET

the code that handles the GET call is as follows:

```
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://lvh.me:8080")
    @GetMapping("/players/player")
    public Player getPlayer(@RequestBody Player newPlayer){
        try {
            return (Player) repository.findFirstByNameLike(newPlayer.getName());
        } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
            throw new PlayerNotFoundException(newPlayer.getName());
```

## UPDATE 1

As Albert commented, i've changed the http://localhost to http://lvh.me to see if by this, the code works, but no exit.
Also i have edited my controller code changing from @PathVariable to @RequestBody (as my POST request to the same controller with a json body is working) also with effect.
Fiinally, thanks to Kevin comments, i've also changed the way to handle the CORS policy from a global approach to a controller approach, also without exit.
i've changed the code above to reflec this changes.

Any comments & suggestions are welcome. Thanks
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can specifically enable CORS for that endpoint using the following:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080")
@GetMapping("/players/{idPlayer}")
public Player getPlayer(@PathVariable Integer idPlayer){
    try {
        return (Player) repository.findById(idPlayer);
    } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
        throw new PlayerNotFoundException(idPlayer);
    }
}
```

If you want to address CORS at a global level you need to create a `WebMvcConfigurer` bean in the class with your main method:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class YourApplication {

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:8080");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Kevin, i've removed the WebMvcConfigurer when i got the POST calls working, as i believed that was not necessary while using the simpleCorsFilter() class. i've added it again to the application but the same error is returned from server"Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/dices/players?{}. (Reason: CORS preflight response did not succeed)."